# Silverlight 5 hardware acceleration

Tags: silverlight, hardware-acceleration, silverlight-5.0

In order to gain the benefits of Hardware acceleration or any performance improvements in Silverlight 5 (beta), whether the client need to have IE9+. Can performance improvement be gained using IE6/IE7.

Whether performance features of Silverlight 5 are browser dependent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way it can be browser dependent. Silverlight is meant to be the same cross browser and close platform.

Another thing that makes me think so is the fact that we can run Silverlight out of browser with the same hardware acceleration benefits.

Comment: I saw this statement in SL5 beta release notes - "Hardware acceleration is enabled in windowless mode with Internet Explorer 9". Can you clarify?

Comment: This line just means that when we will switch to windowless mode(let me know if you don't know about cons and pros) we will be using IE 9 hardware acceleration.This is true for IE9 only.Performance benefits are for all platforms( H.264 hardware acceleration,GPU accelerated 3D support)

Comment: Silverlight 5 [use XNA](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2011/04/13/what-s-new-in-silverlight-5-beta-3d-graphics-support.aspx) for 3D which use [DirectX](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/60113/369870.aspx). Please correct me if I am wrong. If I am correct than 3D will not work for Mac so it will not be cross platform feature.